# How to average data for a variable over a number of timesteps

Tags: dataframe, numpy, matplotlib, multidimensional-array, netcdf4

I was wondering if anyone could shed some light into how I can average this data:

I have a .nc file with data (dimensions: 2029,64,32) which relates to time, latitude and longitude. Using these commands I can plot individual timesteps:

```
timestep = data.variables['precip'][0]
plt.imshow(timestep)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Giving a graph in this format for the 0th timestep:
[image: see picture]

I was wondering if there was any way to average this first dimension (the snapshots in time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to take a mean over all times, try using [`np.mean`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html) where you use the `axis` keyword to say which axis you want to average.

```
time_avaraged = np.mean(data.variables['precip'], axis = 0)
```

If you have `NaN` values then `np.mean` will give `NaN` for that lon/lat point. If you'd rather ignore them then use [`np.nanmean`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nanmean.html).

If you want to do specific times only, e.g. the first 1000 time steps, then you could do

```
time_avaraged = np.mean(data.variables['precip'][:1000,:,:], axis = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you're using **pandas** and **numpy** this may help you.[Look for more details](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python/moving-average-python/#use-the-pandas-module-to-calculate-the-moving-average)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = np.array([10,5,8,9,15,22,26,11,15,16,18,7])
d = pd.Series(data)
print(d.rolling(4).mean())
```